# ar1 and glmm with glmmTMB?

Tags: glmmtmb

I wonder if I'm not actually totally barking up the wrong tree. I have a longitudinal dataset with 10 measurement time points ("mtp"), the subject variable is "id" and I want to measure if happiness predicts whether a child will be born or not ("newborn", binary outcome). To do this, I have longitudinally lagged happiness by 1 and am now running a GLMM with glmmTMB.

Now my question: is it advisable to consider autocorrelations via ar1 here and wouldn't that also additionally mean that the previous measured value in newborn has an influence on the subsequent measured value in newborn? In the sense of, if no child was born before, it is more likely that no child was born now. Or does the autocorrelation in this case only refer to the predictors?

And in this context, is it advisable to (additionally) consider varying slopes and intercepts (random-slopes-random-intercept model) between subjects?

My current code is (which is somehow not converging by the way):

````
  dplyr::mutate(happiness-lag1 = lag(happiness, n = 1, default = NA))

glmmmodel <- glmmTMB(newborn ~ happiness-lag1 + age + sex + (1 + happiness-lag1|id) + ar1(-1 + index|id), data = longitudinal, family = binomial)```
````